# Resize font depending on bootstrap column size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap 3 and i'm having the next issue. I need to resize the font of li elements inside a column of bootstrpa depending on its size.

My code is this

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                <!-- Parte derecha -->
                <section>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="premio" ng-repeat="premio in Premios">
                            <div class="jtextfill">
                                <div class="imagePremio">
                                    <img alt="" ng-src="images/{{premio.PremioColor}}.png" />
                                    <div ng-class="getCSSclass(premio.PremioPuntosRequeridos)">
                                        <p>{{premio.PremioPuntosRequeridos}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{premio.PremioNombre}}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
```

So i what i want is to set font size of my li.premio in css to 10px when is col-sm-7 and font size to 12px when is col-md-9. Can someone guide me please?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Check out the function `hasClass()` in the [API Docs](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: @RenéRoth `hasClass()` won't work, because the `div` has all the classes all the time. You could try something like this: http://davidwalsh.name/device-state-detection-css-media-queries-javascript Do you have more divs that sum up to 12 or just that one?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://bootply.com/121977

Comment: @RenéRoth yeah i have more divs, but i'm only interested on resizing that class of the css

Comment: @azeós yeah i have more divs, but i'm only interested on resizing that class of the css

Comment: @Skelly there i'm diretly asking for device sizes, not based on bootstrap columns

Comment: `var cols = Math.round($('.parent').width() / $('.parent > div').outerWidth())` That will give you the number of columns. You'll have to check it onResize and do whatever you want.

Comment: Ok.. but Boostrap column sizing is based on media queries

Comment: @Skelly yes, i will have to do that. Can't find what i expected

Comment: What about my JS solution? Another way is to add four elements (visible-xs, visible-sm, visible-md, visible-lg) and check with JS which one is visible.

Comment: @azeós i've already do it with media queries. Ty anyway

Comment: If it's just a case of displaying a different font based on the media query then you should be able to do it in css. see here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/